# Laravel private method returns null but with variable but returns proper response with hardcoded int

Tags: php, laravel, transactions, insert

```
    private function subtractCharges($amount){
        if($amount < 50000){
            // charge 3% only
            $sum = $amount - (0.03 * $amount);
            return $sum;
        } elseif($amount >50000 && $amount < 250000){
            // charge 3% + 50 naira
            $sum = $amount - ((0.03 * $amount) + 5000);
            return $sum;
        } elseif ($amount > 300000){
            // charge 3% + 150 capped at 3000
            $charge = ((0.03 * $amount) + 15000);
            $sum = $charge > 300000 ? $amount - 300000 : $amount - $charge;
            return $sum;
        }
    }
```

it returns null when used in the code below:

```
    public function giveFromWallet($org_id, $amount, $name, $purpose){
        // check if sufficient funds in wallet to give
        $amountKobo = $amount * 100;
        if ($this->balance() >= $amountKobo) {
            // deduct the product->price from user wallet
            if(DB::transaction(function () use ($org_id, $amountKobo, $name, $purpose) {
                // deposit to the user
                DB::table('transactions')->insert([
                    'organisation_id' => $org_id,
                    'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
                    'admin_id' => 'nill',
                    'amount' => $this->subtractCharges($amountKobo),//error happens here
                    'user_amount' => $amountKobo,
                    'name' => auth()->user()->name,
                    'email' => auth()->user()->email,
                    'purpose' => $purpose,
                    'type' => 'Deposit',
                    'auth_code' => 'nill',
                    'created_at' => Carbon::now()
                ]);
                // add revenue/earnings
                $this->revenue($this->calculateRevenue($amountKobo), auth()->user()->id, $org_id, $name);
                // deduct the amount from the user's account
                $this->deduct(auth()->user()->id, $amountKobo, $name, $purpose);
            }, 1)){
                return back()->with('status', 'You have given '.$this->toNaira($amountKobo).' to '.$name);
            }else{
                return back()->with('error', 'Transaction incomplete, contact admin');
            };
        } else {
            return back()->with('error', "Transaction failed, Insufficient funds!");
        }
    }
```

Also, transactions are supposed to reverse if one fails but when I move **$this->deduct()** and **$this->revenue()** to the top of the transaction, they pass while the **DB::table('transactions')** fails.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If `$amount` in the `subtractCharges()` function would equal 50000 or if it is between 250000 and 300000 then the function would not return anything (or null). Perhaps that is the problem?

Comment: @Elvis The `subtractCharges()` function does not return a value when `$amount` equals 50000 or when `$amount` >= 250000 and <= 300000. Those if-checks don't cover all possible `$amount` values. I don't know how else to explain it.

Comment: Ok I understand now. Thank you. Do you see why the transaction doesn’t roll others back when one fails?

Comment: Voted your answer up but unfortunately my votes don’t count yet

Comment: I'm not sure about the transactions issue, but if one of the queries throws an exception, all should be rolled back. But please note that `DB::transaction` does not return true/false for success. I think you should wrap that in a try/catch block to catch the Exception it throws on failure.